# Firebase iOS SDK cannot access Realtime DB behind Proxy

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My application tried to access Firebase Realtime DB behind corporate HTTP(S) proxy, but failed.
FIRAuth returned user information (AuthDataResult), but FIRDatabase did not returned any data.
I'm afraid FIRDatabase does not use HTTP(S) but webSocket, is there any way to access the DB behind the proxy?

Comment: In order for us to help you, you must include more useful information. 
for example: What language is your application build in, what is the AuthDataResult message can be one of the first one that you include in the edit of this post.

Comment: I'm using iOS - Swift to build my application.
AuthDataResult is defined as follows:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/AuthDataResult?hl=ja

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rest api : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/ and add your proxy.